# Handling real parts in complex numbers

Tags: complex

I have a problem understanding how Mathematica handles real values in complex numbers. E.g.

```
a \[Element] Reals;
b \[Element] Reals;
z = a + b I;
t = z^2 + Conjugate[z]
```

gives the somewhat unexpected answer

```
(a + I b)^2 + Conjugate[a] - I Conjugate[b]
```

while

```
t = z^2 + Conjugate[z] // ComplexExpand
```

gives the more 'correct'

```
a + a^2 - b^2 + I (-b + 2 a b)
```

I don't understand why `Conjugate` does not compute to `a - b i` in the first case.

Further,

```
Re[t]
```

does not give the expected

```
a + a^2 - b^2
```

but instead

```
-Im[-b + 2 a b] + Re[a + a^2 - b^2]
```

which I don't understand.

Is there someone that could kindly explain this to me, and perhaps link to some document that have 'exercises' in complex arithmetic using Mathematica that one could practise on? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a \[Element] Reals;` has no effect. It evaluates `a`, checks to see if the result can be identified as real or not, yields `True`, `False`, or `a \[Element] Reals` (if it can't decide), and finally throws away the result using `;`.

I suggest you look up `ComplexExpand` or `Simplify` with `Assumptions`.